# How to make output without 00000?

Tags: c++

I want to subtract from this number and make the output in string,
but I want to remove these zeros

When I print the number in float, these zeros disappear.

```
int main(){

    string money = "5000";

    float r = atof(money.c_str()) - 1000;
    cout << r << endl;
    cout << to_string(r);


    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

```
4000
4000.000000
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are imprecise. What looks to you like 5000 is often represented internally as 5000.00000000972 or similar.  `operator<<` rounded off the extra garbage for you, but it looks like `to_string` wasn't as smart. Side note: Money is often better handled in integers with the smallest possible increment (pennies for example) as the basic unit. This prevents floating point errors.

Comment: That's a good dupe, but it doesn't address how to get around this problem. If you want `cout`-like behaviour, [use an `ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to get it: `string my_to_string(float r)
    {
        ostringstream fmt;
        fmt << r;
        return fmt.str();
    
    }` Not that this is not ideal. Floating point numbers are imprecise ([Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)), and this imprecision can lead to other errors.